# change project svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I  check out a project with subclipse in a repository, and i want to check it this project in a different repository then the first one.
so how i can change the repository?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about changing the repo, rather just creating a new one.

Comment: You can try with `Team > Switch`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [disconnect the project from the current repository and reconnect it with another](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/scm/svn/disconnect-and-reconnect-svn-project-to-another-location-subclipse-version).

Comment: By "project folder already exists" is not a warning for me, it's an error. I can't continue from there.

Comment: @shantanu when you disconnect, making sure "delete existing svn meta data"